# T SQL Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string from VARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, type-conversion

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I have a date stored as `varchar(MAX)` in the format of:

```
2019-02-18
```

However, I want it in the British format `dd/mm/yyyy` (103).

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DateField, 103) AS "JobStartDate"
FROM tblTest
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What am I missing?

Update: The date is initially stored as varchar max as it is coming from a 3rd party system.  I have no control over this and I completly understand this is the wrong format, but this is what I have been given.

Comment: `select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast(DateField as date), 103) AS "JobStartDate" from tblTest`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Why are you storing dates as a `varchar` at all, and *why* do you "**need**" 2GB worth of characters to store a date? Also, the format `yyyy-MM-dd` is unambiguous with the `date` datatype. The style code you have provided, however, is for the format `dd/MM/yyyy; as that's why it's failing. Fix your data type, fix the problem.

Comment: please check your data. thast code will be work for convert nvarchar to date time. maybe you have at least one record out of datetime format

Comment: @MahdiRahimi it won't work when the OP is telling SQL Server the date is in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`. `'2019-02-18'` is in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, so of course it's going to fail.

Comment: @Larnu check this code on your sql sever its work `SELECT (CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/10/2012'))`

Comment: @MahdiRahimi `'10/10/2012'` is in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` (impossible to know) **not** `yyyy-MM-dd`. It's not the same. Try what the OP has, `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2019-02-18', 103) AS "JobStartDate"`; you'll see it **doesn't** work.

Comment: you can use format function in sql server `FORMAT(DateTime variable , 'd' , 'en-gb')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a date stored as `varchar(MAX)`

**There's your problem right there.**
Not only you are using the wrong data type to store dates, you are also using `max` which is a known performance killer.

**The solution to the problem is to alter the table and store dates in a `Date` data type** - but first, you must look up all the objects that depends on that column and make sure they will not break or change them as well.

Assuming this can't be done, or as a temporary workaround, you must first convert the data you have to `Date`, and then convert it back to a string representation of that date using the `103` style to get `dd/mm/yyyy`.
Since `yyyy-mm-dd` string format is not culture dependent with the date data type, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), TRY_CAST(DateField As Date), 103) As [JobStartDate]
FROM tblTest
```

Note I've used `try_cast` and not `cast` since the database can't stop you from storing values that can't be converted to dates in that column.

Answer (score 2):

You want to format the `DateField` column and not convert it to date.
So first convert it to `DATE` and then apply the format:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE, DateField, 21), 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS JobStartDate
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0dbe727d51117bf10e672cf7cdf224f7).

Comment: [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: When possible, use `convert` - and this string representation format has a conversion style which is 103.

Comment: @forpas I have tried but still receive the same message

Comment: @Michael Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c2664ec0ed8004e8d7f98c5533dadc1 As you can see the code works. So maybe there is something wrong with your data.